[Flutter Engine]Frame drops caused by toImageSync
My application has certain frame drops in some sliding scenes. After checking, I found that an abnormal time-consuming method named DoMakeRasterSnapshot appeared in the trace. Finally, I found that the abnormal frame drops were caused by the upper layer calling the toImageSync method.
Trace Impeller(Enabled) Flutter version 2.24.4 OS:Android
What is the reason for this problem? Is there any optimization solution?

I bet you're just asking for more than the phone chip can provide.  That's life.
